# Decode Base64 String Natively in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, cast, string-manipulation

I have a `varchar` column in a table in SQL Server that holds a **Base64-encoded** text string,
which I would like to decode into its **plain text** equivalent.

Does SQL Server have any **native** functionality to handle this type of thing?

Here is a sample base64 string:

```
cm9sZToxIHByb2R1Y2VyOjEyIHRpbWVzdGFtcDoxNDY4NjQwMjIyNTcxMDAwIGxhdGxuZ3tsYXRpdHVkZV9lNzo0MTY5ODkzOTQgbG9uZ2l0dWRlX2U3Oi03Mzg5NjYyMTB9IHJhZGl1czoxOTc2NA==
```

which decodes to:

```
role:1 producer:12 timestamp:1468640222571000 latlng{latitude_e7:416989394 longitude_e7:-738966210} radius:19764
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT
    (
        VARCHAR(MAX), 
        CAST('' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("BASE64_COLUMN"))', 'VARBINARY(MAX)')
    ) AS RESULT
FROM
    (
        SELECT 'cm9sZToxIHByb2R1Y2VyOjEyIHRpbWVzdGFtcDoxNDY4NjQwMjIyNTcxMDAwIGxhdGxuZ3tsYXRpdHVkZV9lNzo0MTY5ODkzOTQgbG9uZ2l0dWRlX2U3Oi03Mzg5NjYyMTB9IHJhZGl1czoxOTc2NA==' AS BASE64_COLUMN
    ) A
```

Output:

```
role:1 producer:12 timestamp:1468640222571000 latlng{latitude_e7:416989394 longitude_e7:-738966210} radius:19764
```

Just swap out `BASE64_COL_NAME` for your column name, or you can replace `sql:column("BASE64_COLUMN")` with `sql:variable("@base64variable")` if you want to use a declared variable e.g. if you are making a function or something.

It makes use of an XSL transform using built-in XML functionality (since SQL Server 2005)

Comment: For those who are getting NULL add `==` at the end of the base64String you are trying to decode

Answer (score 2):

Just as an alternative, Azure SQL Database supports decoding base64 encoded values into varbinary which can then be converted into a varchar value.

`convert(varchar(max), BASE64_DECODE([BASE64_ENCODED_COLUMN_NAME]))`

[BASE64_DECODE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/base64-decode-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current)